# Paginación dentro de foreach de Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6

Necesito hacer saltos de página en un **@foreach** pero obviamente en el último elemento del array también realiza un salto que no es deseable. No me queda otra que usar un for, controlando la cantidad de elementos del array?.

```
@foreach ($paginas as $pagina)
    <p>{{ $pagina->contenido }}</p>
    <div class="page_break"></div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, lo estás haciendo bien pero a medias. En el controller, indica lo siguiente:

```
$paginas = ModelPaginas::paginate(10);
return view('tuView', compact('paginas'));
```

Esto hará que las páginas las pagine de 10 en 10. Las pasarás de este modo a tu vista.

Entonces, en el blade verás los 10 primeros pero claro, te faltan más. Para mostrar las páginas que faltan y poder ir navegando, utiliza lo siguiente:

```
{!! $paginas->links() !!}
```

En resumen, te quedaría así:

```
@foreach ($paginas as $pagina)
    <p>{{ $pagina->contenido }}</p>
@endforeach
<div class="page_break"></div>
     {!! $paginas->links() !!}
</div>
```